# CAF - How to debug media crashes?

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I need to debug a crash that is occurring randomly during media playback on a CAF application. This appears to be a content issue, but the only error I get from the cast receiver on the crash is:

```
media_player.js:64  [1701.609s] [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/102
```

The ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/102 refers to a MEDIA_ERR_DECODE, but there is no specific information about what the decoding error actually was.

Is there a way to probe the cast receiver for a more detailed error? Is there a better way to debug video playback issues?

This is an HLS stream with ads inserted (using a discontinuity).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome Remote Debugger to debug a Cast application. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging